# 417 Expectation Failed when doing POST request using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, http, exception

I need to create a POST request using RestTemplate to an authentication endpoint to get a token. The endpoint requires a raw JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
   "client_id" : "12345"
   "client_secret" : "12345"
}
```

I am tried adding the json as a map into the HttpEntity along with the `Application/Json` content type in the hedaer. the raw JSON is the only thing that i needs

```
String url = "https://oauth/token";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MultiValueMap<String,String> map  = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("client_id", "b890" );
        map.add("client_secret", "576a0");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
        assert(response.hasBody());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        JsonNode jsonNode;
        try
        {
            jsonNode = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
            token = jsonNode.get("access_token").asText();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(token);
```

I get the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 417 Expectation Failed
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:445) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at monitor.ScheduledTasks.getToken(ScheduledTasks.java:86) ~[classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

Comment: Is similar request working on RestClient or Postman or curl?

Comment: yes, I've tried it on postman, the API is working correctly

Comment: Dis you find out the solution?

Comment: I think eventually, play around with the type of object you use for the body, instead of mulivaluemap try just map or an object